# show child row just after parent row based on latest comment date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm creating and showing blog comments data where I have to make data in order.
Below is the table structure and insert query for table which is used:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails](
    [CommentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CommentUserName] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [CommentText] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CommentApprovedByUserID] [int] NULL,
    [CommentPostDocumentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CommentDate] [datetime] NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [HtmlComment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CommentIsSpam] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_Blog_MainComment_CommentIsSpam]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [CommentIsApproved] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_Blog_MainComment_CommentIsApproved]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [CommentEmail] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [CommentInfo] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ReplyCommentID] [int] NULL,
    [IsRejected] [bit] NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_Blog_MainComment_CommentIsRejected]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [PageType] [varchar](50) NULL CONSTRAINT [DEFAULT_PageType]  DEFAULT ('Blog'),
    [BlogSiteID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] ([CommentID], [CommentUserName], [CommentText], [CommentApprovedByUserID], [CommentPostDocumentID], [CommentDate], [HtmlComment], [CommentIsSpam], [CommentIsApproved], [CommentEmail], [CommentInfo], [ReplyCommentID], [IsRejected], [PageType], [BlogSiteID]) VALUES (142, N'Siddappa', N'Siddappa commented on vikash comment', 70, 15, CAST(N'2016-12-30 03:52:04.533' AS DateTime), N'<div class="reply-comment-section"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="post-comment-section"><p id="pBlogReplyCommentorName"><p id="sReplyCommentorName" class="blogcommentname">Siddappa</p><span id="sBlogReplyCommentDate">Dec30,2016 3:21PM</span></p><p class="comment-detail" id="pBlogReplyCommentDetails">Siddappa commented on vikash comment</p><div class="comment-reply"><ul><li id="HiddenMainreply"><img id="imgMainReply" class="contributors-list" src="/WorldVentures/getmedia/cfea575e-2f94-48f4-949f-fada2ca45e4e/icon_reply_1.png.aspx?width=128&height=128&ext=.png" alt="Reply comment icon"><a class="joinus-link" id="btnCommentReply" href="#" target="_self">Reply</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>', 0, 1, N'siddappa@gmail.com', NULL, 141, 0, N'Blog', 17)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] ([CommentID], [CommentUserName], [CommentText], [CommentApprovedByUserID], [CommentPostDocumentID], [CommentDate], [HtmlComment], [CommentIsSpam], [CommentIsApproved], [CommentEmail], [CommentInfo], [ReplyCommentID], [IsRejected], [PageType], [BlogSiteID]) VALUES (145, N'Suresh', N'Suresh commented on Mansur comment.', 70, 15, CAST(N'2016-12-30 03:55:50.197' AS DateTime), N'<div class="reply-comment-section"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="post-comment-section"><p id="pBlogReplyCommentorName"><p id="sReplyCommentorName" class="blogcommentname">Suresh</p><span id="sBlogReplyCommentDate">Dec30,2016 3:24PM</span></p><p class="comment-detail" id="pBlogReplyCommentDetails">Suresh commented on Mansur comment.</p><div class="comment-reply"><ul><li id="HiddenMainreply"><img id="imgMainReply" class="contributors-list" src="/WorldVentures/getmedia/cfea575e-2f94-48f4-949f-fada2ca45e4e/icon_reply_1.png.aspx?width=128&height=128&ext=.png" alt="Reply comment icon"><a class="joinus-link" id="btnCommentReply" href="#" target="_self">Reply</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>', 0, 1, N'suresh@gmail.com', NULL, 144, 0, N'Blog', 17)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] ([CommentID], [CommentUserName], [CommentText], [CommentApprovedByUserID], [CommentPostDocumentID], [CommentDate], [HtmlComment], [CommentIsSpam], [CommentIsApproved], [CommentEmail], [CommentInfo], [ReplyCommentID], [IsRejected], [PageType], [BlogSiteID]) VALUES (141, N'Vikash', N'this is vikash main comment', 70, 15, CAST(N'2016-12-30 03:50:46.113' AS DateTime), N'<div class="main-comment-section"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="post-comment-section"><p id="sCommentorName" class="blogcommentname">Vikash</p><span id="sBlogPostedDate">Dec30,2016 3:20PM</span></p><p class="comment-detail" id="pBlogCommentDetails">this is vikash main comment</p><div class="comment-reply"><ul><li id="Hiddenreply"><img id="imgReply" src="/WorldVentures/getmedia/cfea575e-2f94-48f4-949f-fada2ca45e4e/icon_reply_1.png.aspx?width=128&height=128&ext=.png" alt="Reply comment icon"><a class="joinus-link" id="btnComment" href="#" target="_self">Reply</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>', 0, 1, N'vikash@gmail.com', NULL, NULL, 0, N'Blog', 17)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] ([CommentID], [CommentUserName], [CommentText], [CommentApprovedByUserID], [CommentPostDocumentID], [CommentDate], [HtmlComment], [CommentIsSpam], [CommentIsApproved], [CommentEmail], [CommentInfo], [ReplyCommentID], [IsRejected], [PageType], [BlogSiteID]) VALUES (143, N'Megha', N'this is megha comment.', 70, 15, CAST(N'2016-12-30 03:53:03.633' AS DateTime), N'<div class="reply-comment-section"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="post-comment-section"><p id="pBlogReplyCommentorName"><p id="sReplyCommentorName" class="blogcommentname">Megha</p><span id="sBlogReplyCommentDate">Dec30,2016 3:22PM</span></p><p class="comment-detail" id="pBlogReplyCommentDetails">this is megha comment.</p><div class="comment-reply"><ul><li id="HiddenMainreply"><img id="imgMainReply" class="contributors-list" src="/WorldVentures/getmedia/cfea575e-2f94-48f4-949f-fada2ca45e4e/icon_reply_1.png.aspx?width=128&height=128&ext=.png" alt="Reply comment icon"><a class="joinus-link" id="btnCommentReply" href="#" target="_self">Reply</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>', 0, 1, N'megha@gmail.com', NULL, 141, 0, N'Blog', 17)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] ([CommentID], [CommentUserName], [CommentText], [CommentApprovedByUserID], [CommentPostDocumentID], [CommentDate], [HtmlComment], [CommentIsSpam], [CommentIsApproved], [CommentEmail], [CommentInfo], [ReplyCommentID], [IsRejected], [PageType], [BlogSiteID]) VALUES (144, N'Mansur', N'mansur commented on vikash comment.', 70, 15, CAST(N'2016-12-30 03:54:12.613' AS DateTime), N'<div class="reply-comment-section"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="post-comment-section"><p id="pBlogReplyCommentorName"><p id="sReplyCommentorName" class="blogcommentname">Mansur</p><span id="sBlogReplyCommentDate">Dec30,2016 3:23PM</span></p><p class="comment-detail" id="pBlogReplyCommentDetails">mansur commented on vikash comment.</p><div class="comment-reply"><ul><li id="HiddenMainreply"><img id="imgMainReply" class="contributors-list" src="/WorldVentures/getmedia/cfea575e-2f94-48f4-949f-fada2ca45e4e/icon_reply_1.png.aspx?width=128&height=128&ext=.png" alt="Reply comment icon"><a class="joinus-link" id="btnCommentReply" href="#" target="_self">Reply</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>', 0, 1, N'mansur@gmail.com', NULL, 141, 0, N'Blog', 17)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Blog_CommentDetails] OFF
GO
```

and I'm using currently below query to check who is replied on his parent comment:

```
WITH CTE AS ( SELECT CommentID ,
                    CommentUserName,
                     CommentPostDocumentID ,
                     CommentIsApproved,
                     CommentDate ,
                     ReplyCommentID ,
                     CommentID AS ThreadID ,
                     CAST( CommentID AS VARCHAR( MAX ) ) AS PathStr
              FROM Blog_CommentDetails AS T WITH(NOLOCK)
              WHERE ReplyCommentID IS NULL
              UNION ALL
              SELECT T.CommentID ,
                     T.CommentUserName,
                     t.CommentPostDocumentID ,
                     t.CommentIsApproved,
                     T.CommentDate ,
                     T.ReplyCommentID ,
                     CTE.ThreadID ,
                     PathStr + '-'+ CAST( T.ReplyCommentID AS VARCHAR( MAX ) ) AS PathStr
              FROM Blog_CommentDetails AS T WITH(NOLOCK)
              JOIN CTE 
              ON T.ReplyCommentID = CTE.CommentID
              WHERE T.ReplyCommentID IS NOT NULL )
            SELECT *
            FROM CTE
            WHERE CommentPostDocumentID = 15 AND CommentIsApproved=1
            ORDER BY ThreadID ,
                        PathStr ,
                        CommentDate DESC
```

After using this query I'm able to get the hierarchy like below:

Main comment: Vikash
   reply comment: Mansur has the latest comment so he seat just after vikash

if someone will again reply on vikash who will be seat after vikash it is happening based on latest inserted comment.

But if any user will reply on any reply comment like in this query suresh has replied on mansur so he should have to seat after mansur but he is seating in the last.

Below is the attached image for your reference:

[image: Comment Image]

Please let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Please don't deface your post by rolling back our improvements.

Comment: i did not get any reply from any of the member so i thought that may be i did not make format correctly due to that no one is replying so i again posted my question.

Comment: Can anyone reply on the above issue? I am waiting for that.